# laravel middleware didn't get error codes or session messages in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

There is page where i submit id and then middleware checks if it's right and the redirects to another route. Middleware works good but, i can't get messages in my blades.

middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
        $exists =Kuponas::where('id', $request->id)->exists();
        if (!$exists) {
            return \Redirect::to(url('/'))->with('pin','Duomenys neteisingi, patikrinkite ');
        }
        return $next($request);
  }
```

Blade:

```
@error('pin')
  <p>
    <i><b>Error:</b> {{ $message }}</i>
  </p>
  @enderror
```

or

```
@if ($message = Session::get('pin'))
<div class="alert alert-success alert-block"
    style="position:relative;left:260px;width: 50%;text-align: center;">
                    <button type="button" style="position:relative; bottom: 5px; color: white;" s="close"
                        data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                    <strong style="color: white;">{{ $message }}</strong>
                </div>
@endif
```

Doesn't work either if I enter bad value in input.

Comment: this view you are showing is the view returned from the '/' route?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this, Blade:

```
@if(session('pin'))
  <p>
    <i><b>Error:</b> {{ $message }}</i>
  </p>
@endif
```